# Address UITextField with a variable containing the UITextField name

Tags: xcode, sqlite, uitextfield

I create programmatically several `UITextFields` that are showing information from SQLite. The names in SQLite are P01, P02, P03, P04,... As I don't want to duplicate my source code, I like to use a variable to store the SQLite name and then pass the value to a `UITextField`. Something like this:

```
NSString *strName;

for (int iValue= 0; ....
  strName = NSString withFormat:@"P0%d", iValue....
  uitextfield.text = &strName
```

Result will be that the SQLite value from the attribute P01 is shown

Is this possible and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First save all the data you get from SQLite in a NSMutableArray.
Lets name it nameArray.
then do something like this,

```
for(int i=0;i<=nameArray.count;i++)
{
UITextField *movieView=[[UITextField alloc] init ];
 movieView.frame=CGRectMake(5,  20*i, 259, 20);
[movieView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[movieView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[movieView setText:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
 [self.view addSubview:movieView];

}
```